# ./gradlew tasks returns different results depending on calling directory

Tags: android, gradle, gradlew

**Context:** I am trying to solve the following error: `Task 'assembleRelease' not found in root project 'android'.` from CircleCi when it works fine on my local machine.

I noticed if I ran (both locally and on the ci server) `./android/gradlew tasks` it doesn't have any "Build tasks".

However if I move into the directory where gradlew lives and try again, I get all the Build Tasks reported.

`cd android && ./gradlew tasks`

Why is there a difference in what tasks gradlew reports, depending on the directory from which it was called?

I'm using Fastlane to automate my builds with `bundle exec fastlane android beta` from ./ (rather than ./android)